# How to create new database in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My goal is to create a new `database` for new brands that the user will add on the website. I've created a code for doing such task but it is giving me this `exception`:

> **An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Incorrect syntax near 'char'.**

I already looked at the code several times but I still can't find the root cause of the problem.

Here is the code:

```
public static void CreateGuitarBrandsDatabase(string brand)
{
    SqlConnection createBrandData = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Y560\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GuitarItemsDB;Integrated Security=True");
    createBrandData.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdBrandData = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE guitarItem" + brand + "(id int,type char(50),model char(50),price float,image1 char(255),image2 char(255),description text,neck type char(100),body char(100), fretboard char(100),fret char(50),bridge char(100),neck pickup char(100),bridge pickup char(100),hardware_color char(50));", createBrandData);
    cmdBrandData.ExecuteNonQuery();//The exception seems to be pointing right here
    createBrandData.Close();
}
```

Comment: You can't use spaces on the names for columns unless you surround the name with square brakets, like `"[bridge pickup] char(100)"`

Comment: if brand is user supplied (sounds like it is) this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @dman2306 - oh crap! well thanks for the info.

Comment: In this case you can't parametrize the query, but you *can* make sure (and do that server side) that the "brand" contains only letters (and maybe digits). Or use a different configuration, where "brand" is a regular column in your one "guitarItem" table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have issue in defining column name. Following column names are seems to have issue in which each column name has been separated by
space :

```
neck type char(100) --> name_type char(100)
neck pickup char(100) --> neck_pickup char(100)
bridge pickup char(100) --> bridge_pickup char(100)
```

Your complete query should be :

```
SqlCommand cmdBrandData = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE guitarItem" + brand + "(id int,type char(50),model char(50),price float,image1 char(255),image2 char(255),description text,
neck_type char(100),body char(100), fretboard char(100),fret char(50),bridge char(100),neck_pickup char(100),
bridge_pickup char(100),hardware_color char(50));", createBrandData);
```

If you want to have column name with word having space in between them, then you should enclose them in square bracket([]):

```
SqlCommand cmdBrandData = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE guitarItem" + brand + "(id int,type char(50),model char(50),price float,image1 char(255),image2 char(255),description text,
[neck type] char(100),body char(100), fretboard char(100),fret char(50),bridge char(100),[neck pickup] char(100),
[bridge pickup] char(100),hardware_color char(50));", createBrandData);
```

Comment: Watch out for those spaces when you are working in the database world!!